# WPF Toolkit Community Edition Property Grid: New Item Types in Collection Editor

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, wpftoolkit, propertygrid

I use the property grid of WPF Toolkit CE.
On adding an object to a collection, the opened dialog shows a combobox to select the new type to be added. In the documentation I read for `NewItemTypesAttribute`:
*This attribute can decorate the collection properties (i.e., IList) of your selected object in order to control the types that will be allowedto be instantiated in the CollectionControl.*

But I cannot get it working.
Here are the last variant I tried:

```
namespace TestPropertyGrid
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
      this.PGrid.SelectedObject = new MyObject();
    }
  }

  public class MyObject
  {
    [NewItemTypes(typeof(MyBaseObj), typeof(MyObj1))]
    [Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
    public ArrayList ListOfObjects { get; set; } = new ArrayList();
  }

  public class MyBaseObj
  {
  }

  public class MyObj1
  {
  }
}
```

In this case the "select type" list is empty.

I try to use a `List<object>` instead of `ArrayList` but the list contains only the type Object.

Initialy I wanted a `List<MyBaseObj>` (would be an abstract class) and add objects of type `MyObj1`resp `MyObj2` which would both inherit from `MyBaseObj`. Same as in the documentation sample:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Community myObj = new Community();
      myObj.Members = new List<Person>();
      this.PGrid.SelectedObject = myObj;
    }
  }

  public class Community
  {
    [NewItemTypes(typeof(Man), typeof(Woman))]
    [Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
    public IList<Person> Members { get; set; }
  }

  public class Person { }
  public class Man : Person  { }
  public class Woman : Person  { }
```

I hope I could explain my problem clearly and someone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange... it seems, this is not 100% implemented.
Now I made my own CollectionEditor and set the types from this attribute myself.

```
class MyCollectionEditor : TypeEditor<CollectionControlButton>
{
  protected override void SetValueDependencyProperty()
  {
    ValueProperty = CollectionControlButton.ItemsSourceProperty;
  }

  protected override void ResolveValueBinding(PropertyItem propertyItem)
  {
    var type = propertyItem.PropertyType;
    Editor.ItemsSourceType = type;
    // added
    AttributeCollection attrs = propertyItem.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes;
    Boolean attrFound = false;
    foreach(Attribute attr in attrs)
    {
      if (attr is NewItemTypesAttribute)
      {
        Editor.NewItemTypes = ((NewItemTypesAttribute)attr).Types;
        attrFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    // end added
    if (!attrFound)
    {
      if (type.BaseType == typeof(System.Array))
      {
        Editor.NewItemTypes = new List<Type>() { type.GetElementType() };
      }
      else if (type.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 0)
      {
        Editor.NewItemTypes = new List<Type>() { type.GetGenericArguments()[0] };
      }
    }
    base.ResolveValueBinding(propertyItem);
  }
}
```